# Querying Oracle in Java using JDBC Result Set is Null, Query is fine in SQLDeveloper

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I'm working on some development in Java touching an Oracle database.  I have been able to successfully connect and pull some data from the database, however, when I try to use a query that will pull a subsection of the data at a time I am getting a null ResultSet.

```
    HashMap<String, String> tableSchema = getTableSchema(connection, tableName);
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = tableSchema.entrySet().iterator().next();
    int rows = (getTableRowCount(connection, tableName));
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i+= 500){
        String query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY " + entry.getKey() + ") rn FROM " + tableName + " a) WHERE rn > " + i + " and rn < " + (i+500) + ";";
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if(rs == null){
         // Always the case
        } 
     }
```

If I execute a query that is simply

`query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;`

the resultSet is full of data.  I have also taken the result of the construction of the query string (via println) and pasted it into Oracle SQL Developer, where it has produced results.

So I suppose this brings up a few questions and answering any would likely solve the problem.  Is there a better way to iterate through an Oracle database table in Java (some of these tables are too big so I won't be able to load them wholesale into memory) rather than this query?  Is there a different type of query that I can use?  Is there any known reason why this would be returning null when the same query works in SQL Developer?

Comment: First, if you're dynamically building a query, it's always a good idea to print/ log it before executing it.  If you're not getting the data you expect, it's likely down to the query you're building being incorrect.  Seeing what you've actually built makes it much easier to see how that differs from what you want.  Second, you should use parameterized queries and bind the value of `i`.  Third, doing a `select * from table` doesn't read the entire table into memory (generally) so it doesn't make sense to page through data like this.

Comment: Strange, javadoc says that executeQuery never returns NULL, then why are you checking for null value at all ? : `.... Returns: a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the given query; never null` ==> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29 Maybe there is an error somwhere else in the code, but you ignore exception in the try-catch block and you are not aware of it?

Comment: Did you try without the semicolon (`+ ";"`) at the end of your query string? Are you getting an `SQLException` anywhere in your logs?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Removing the semicolon at the end did it.  I don't know what to tell you, kordirko, but I had a print line inside of the null check saying "THIS IS NULL" and it was always being spat out.  Later when trying to perform an operation on the resultset the exception catching logic was triggered.

I'm going to take a look, I assumed that having 300+ million rows would make that infeasible, but if it works...